# How to display the properties of a Scheduled Task?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have  C# app that uses a Form to set a bunch of settings. Those settings can be read by a Console App so it can run via the built in Windows Task Scheduler. 
I would like to be able to simply open up a scheduled task as if I had just opened it from the gui in Windows so the user can set all the settings for the scheduled task. 
I know I can use a library like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx but I would rather not have to recreate all the options in a WinForm when everything is already available in Windows. 
Does anyone know how I can programattically display the built in Windows Task Scheduler from C#?

Additionally: this need to be able to run on XP and Server 2003 and it looks like taskschd.msc was introduced in Vista. Also I would like to be able open a specific task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library at CodeProject that you reference also have the method Task.DisplayPropertySheet.

I assume that this wraps IProvideTaskPage::GetPage etc and so should allow you to show the user interface without having to replicate it yourself. My understanding is though that you can only show the GUI as it looks in XP, the new style Vista/7 GUI is not available via this interface.